# Google Analytics for one site with language specific domains

Tags: google-analytics

I have one site that serves EN and FR users. Each language has it's own domain,  so englishcontent.com and frenchcontent.com. I'm setting up profiles, one for each. For the filters, would this be the correct setting

Type: Custom > Include
Field: Hostname
Pattern englishcontent.com

I would then have a profifile for French with the similar settings.

is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should work, but keep in mind keep always a view without filter, in you case you need to have 4:

EnDomain View
FRDomain View
AllDomain View (No domain filter, but ip filter or any other needed)
Raw View (No Filter at all , this in case of something fails)

Take care of the variation of the domains and your filter. For example whats happens with the www variations or the subdomains.
Greetings

Example

PS: This structure is not the recomended one by Google, it suposes one account per brand, one property per domain and the desired views.
more information on:
https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/course/1/unit/4/lesson/2
[image]

Comment: I do. i have a Raw, i call (z01) - Raw or something like that. Force of habit has me doing that. I learned the hard way :)